# Как скрыть часть номера телефона?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Как можно скрыть часть номера телефона (например, последние четыре цифры заменить на X), а при нажатии показать?

```html
<span class="phone_number">+74951182647<span class="phone_number_active"> Показать</span></span>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вот максимально настраиваемое решение, можете экспериментировать с настройками как угодно:

```js
$(function(){
let holder=$('.phone_number'),
button=$('.phone_number_active'),
number=holder.text(),
symbolsForHide=4,
show=()=>{
  holder.text(number)
  button.removeClass('show').text('Скрыть')
},
hide=()=>{
  holder.text(number.replace(new RegExp('(.+).{'+symbolsForHide+'}$'),"$1"+'x'.repeat(symbolsForHide)))
  button.addClass('show').text('Вскрыть')
}
button.click(function(){
  if($(this).hasClass('show')) show()
  else hide()
})
hide()
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span class="phone_number">+74951182647</span> <span class="phone_number_active show">Показать</span>
```

Comment: @LADYX Я у вас немного изменил HTML структуру, заметьте, и самая распространённая ошибка - неверно указанный селектор, сверьте классы у ваших элементов с теми, что указаны в скрипте.

Comment: @LADYX На здоровье, милейший :3

Answer (score 5):

```js
$(".phone_number .show").click(function(){
  var $parent = $(this).closest(".phone_number");
  $parent.find(".value").text($parent.data("phone"));
  $(this).hide();
  $parent.find(".hide").show();
});

$(".phone_number .hide").click(function(){
  var $parent = $(this).closest(".phone_number");
  var phone = $parent.data("phone");
  phone = phone.substring(0, phone.length - 4) + "xxxx";
  $parent.find(".value").text(phone);

  $(this).hide();
  $parent.find(".show").show();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span class="phone_number" data-phone="+74951182647">
  <span class="value">+7495118xxxx</span>
  <span class="show">Показать</span>
  <span class="hide" style="display:none;">Не показать</span>
</span>
```